# What am I doing wrong?/ return state with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, menu, icons

even though the hamburger is losing popularity I'm making a menu icon that 'morphs' into an 'X' when clicked but I can't return it to the original state when clicked a second time?

with this i would later like to call i menu into view so If there is a better way to accomplish this effect please let me know.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://static.tumblr.com/majy1x4/u18mpz8h2/reset.styles.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">

        *{}

        body{}

        .icon-wrapper{
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;
            height: 14px;
            width: 20px;
            z-index: 2;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .top{
            height: 2px;
            width: 20px;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .middle{
            height: 2px;
            width: 20px;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            position: absolute;
            top: 6px;
            left: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .bottom{
            height: 2px;
            width: 20px;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            position: absolute;
            top: 12px;
            left: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .rotatedown{
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
            top: 6px;
        }

        .rotateup{
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
            top: 6px;
        }



        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="icon-wrapper">

        <div class="top"></div>

        <div class="middle"></div>

        <div class="bottom"></div>

    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('.icon-wrapper').click(aniOpen);
        $('.top').click(aniOpen);
        $('.middle').click(aniOpen);
        $('.bottom').click(aniOpen);
        $('.rotateup').click(aniClose);
        $('.rotatedown').click(aniClose);
        $('.close').click(aniClose);

        function aniOpen(){
            $('.middle').fadeOut('fast');
            $('.top').addClass('rotatedown');
            $('.bottom').addClass('rotateup');
            $('.icon-wrapper').addClass('close');
        }

        function aniClose(){
            $('.middle').fadeIn('fast');
            $('.top').addClass('rotatedown');
            $('.bottom').removeClass('rotateup');
            $('.close').removeClass('close');
        }




    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use toggleClass instead of addClass.. Attach it to a click event

```
$(function(){
$('.element').click(function(){
    $('.class-to-be-switched').toggleClass("class-name");
});
});
```